# LButton Pressed/Released when LButton pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to run some macrio which allow me emulate Left MOuse Button click until Left mouse button is pressed. But i don't know how to force script to stop when I physical release Left mouse button and start sript again once LButton is pressed again. My code looks like this:

```
SetTimer, keyStates, 100

LeftClick:="LButton"
KeyStates: ; SubRoutine
if GetKeyState(LeftClick, "P") {
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 4, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 2, int, 0, int, 0, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 4, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 2, int, 0, int, 0, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 4, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 2, int, 0, int, 0, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 4, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 2, int, 0, int, 0, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 4, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75
            DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 2, int, 0, int, 0, uint, 0, int, 0)
            Sleep 75        
        }
    }
```

I'm complete new in this scripting language so i would be thankful for any help

Comment: It is still a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve: as far as I understand it right now you want to start a 'clicking loop' at the first physical left button click and stop that loop after doing the second physical left button click, right?

Comment: No clicking loop when i physically hold left click. When I release left click it needs stop the loop

Comment: Now it is even more confusing for me :) No clicking loop when you hold the button but when you release it it should stop - how should it stop when it never started?

Comment: OMG :) how can I say it simpler.
The loop needs to be active (clicking) only when I press and hold left mouse button. 
When I stop script stops...

Comment: Well your last statement is simply contradictory -> "No clicking loop when you hold the button" and now "The loop needs to be active (clicking) only when I press and hold left mouse button"

Comment: There should be "No." because ineed it is seems confusing. "No" was answer for a questuion you have asjked in first reply :)

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile because the last closing bracket, `}`, doesn't have a cooresponding opening bracket. Remove it.

Add the line:

```
#Persistent
```

at the top of the script, so the program won't close immediately.

With those corrections the program works.